# How would I see if a specific item is on a list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, list

I have a list called usernames, that stores usernames. I want to see if the specific username is on the list and deny the person if it is.  Code:

```js
var usernames = ["someuser",""];

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on("join", function(room, username == usernames){
    if (username != "" || username == usernames){
   // do something
    }
  })
```

Comment: `if (usernames.includes(username))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
usernames.includes(username)
```